# Why is my example Android application not showing properly?

Tags: android

I created a new project from an example provided in the SDK, using:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>
> Version: Helios Release Build id:
>   20100617-1415

The application builds and runs successfully but doesn't show what it should be showing. This is what it is showing:

[screenshot of improperly shown UI](http://www.flickr.com/photos/51941830@N07/4799160565/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the emulator has not started completely... you have to wait 3 minutes or more. Keep in mind that the emulator is actually a virtual machine (qemu), so it will take 3 to 5 minutes depending on your system resources.

Once the emulator has started, it will show you more than your application: it will be a *completely* functional Android system.

Comment: Oh my ***! you're right ... that first screen that says "Android" is BAD design b/c there is no indication what it's doing.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you do not need to close the emulator after each test. Keep it open during your entire programming session. Whenever you build, the system is smart enough to replace the old copy of your program on the emulator with the new one. This will save you the hassle of starting the emulator repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

That is the boot screen; check out the log output, using `adb logcat` to see what's going on.  The boot process take a while so you should be patient.

Answer (score 1):

You should see your program by now. And remember not to close that window or you'll have to start it over again ;). Just re-run the program (Ctrl-F11), and you'll run the new instance in the emulator.